# SOLR Select parent documents sorted by a field placed on child document

Tags: solr, solrj

I am needing to get the parent documents sorted by a field placed on the childs documents. 
Is this possible? I found ToParentBlockJoinSortField but it is experimental based on the SOLR documentation.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Have you solved that one? If not If your child documents has a reference to parent document. I would store in solr index parents:ref1 ref2
then querying with query filter :     qf:parents:id. If need more help, let me know.

Comment: No, it was a long time ago but I changed to ElasticSearch, much better than SOLR in every way